# how to iterate all the th under a tr and get their values in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a gridview shared by multiple tables, so I generate it dynamically in the code behind. Also I create a filter under each column. Following is the html code for the gridview.

```
<table id=”GridView1”…>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>
    <span>
    Text-Column1
    <br/>
    <input name=”GridView1$ctl01$txtFilter_Column1” id=”txtFilter_Column1” type=”text” value=”110”/>
<th>
    <span>
    Text-Column2
    <br/>
    <input name=”GridView1$ctl01$txtFilter_Column2” id=”txtFilter_Column2” type=”text” />
```

…
For each filter I need to add a change event to refresh the gridview based on the current values from all the filters. Following is my jquery code. My question is since the number of the columns and  corresponding names varies depending on the tables, how do I change the function to iterate the th and get the column names and values?

```
$(myself.get_element()).find("input[id^='txtFilter_']").each(
            function () {
                var input = $(this);

                input.change(
                function () {
                    var filter;                    
                    var col1 = input.closest('tr').find('th')[1].innerText.replace('&nbsp;', '');
                    var col2 = input.closest('tr').find('th')[2].innerText.replace('&nbsp;', '');
                    filter = "Column1 LIKE '" + col1 + "%' AND Column2 LIKE '" + col2 + "%'";

                    $("#hfFilter").val(filter);
                    $("#btnRefresh").click();
                });
            }
        );
```

Comment: I don't have a full picture here, but sending sql from the client is generally a terrible idea because it can allow the user to execute arbitrary sql statements.

Comment: A `tbody` can't have a `th`, they need to be in a `thead` and you need to close them (`</th>`)

Answer (score 0):

You could do `$('Gridview1 tr').children('th').each(function(){ $(this).text()});` to find what the value of all the children are.